# How to select all columns plus an additional expression

Tags: r, data.table

Let's say I start with

```
mtcarsDT<-data.table(mtcars)
```

and I want the equivalent of

```
mtcarsDT[,.(mpg, cyl,  disp,  hp, drat,    wt,  qsec, vs, am, gear, carb, newcol=myFunc())]
```

but I just want to type something short like `mtcarsDT[,.(.SD, newcol=myFunc())` but of course that syntax doesn't work.

Comment: So you want to create a new column in a data.table? Any reason this doesn't work: `mtcarsDT[, newcol := myFunc()]`?

Comment: Yes and No.  I don't really want to create a column, I just want to view the result of the expression next to the existing columns without having to save the column and then delete it later

Comment: What about `copy(mtcarsDT)[, newcol := myFunc()]`

Comment: Well, `cbind(.SD, newcol = f())` or `c(.SD, .(newcol = f()))` should work. I guess you would also benefit from this feature: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2323 (make a shallow copy of the table so that you don't need to remove the new column later)

Comment: @Frank I like the second one, it very closely matches my wrong way of doing it.  Do you want to make it an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My usual way is

```
c(.SD, .(newcol = f())
```

This approach is also useful when applying functions to multiple columns, like

```
c(
  g = lapply(.SD, g),
  f = lapply(.SD, f),
  .(N = .N)
)
```

This syntax works because

- the return value should be a list (of columns);
- `.SD` already is a list;
- `c()` can be used to combine lists; and
- `.()` is an alias for `list()` offered for convenience inside `DT[...]`.

---

*Details*. From `?data.table`

> As long as `j` returns a `list`, each element of the list becomes a column in the resulting `data.table`. This is the default *enhanced* mode.

A similar line shows up twice in the first vignette, `vignette("datatable-intro")`, but unfortunately there are no examples like the OP's. (Maybe one should be added?)

> I don't really want to create a column, I just want to view the result of the expression next to the existing columns without having to save the column and then delete it later

For this use case, the best solution would probably be taking a shallow copy. That functionality is [not available yet](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2323).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cbind`. For example:

```
cbind(mtcarsDT, newcol = sqrt(mtcarsDT$mpg))
```

And of course, you can define the new column and select the new data table:

```
mtcarsDT[, newcol := sqrt(mpg)]
mtcarsDT
```

In these two examples I assumed your function is `sqrt()` for the sake of simplicity.